# How to set a static IP on a `tunnel` network?

Tags: 20.04, netplan, aws, static-ip, tunnel

I am using amazon AWS VPN endpoint and I have a ubuntu 20.04 client for which I would like to have a static IP on the VPN network.
I cannot find any examples on how to setup the `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` config for a `tunnel` and not `ethernet`.
The tunneling protocol is OpenVPN.

Comment: Hi. Do you solve this? I have the same issue and can't find anything.